# Count number of lines in CSV with Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, count, lines

I'm trying to think of a way to count the number of lines in a .csv file using Javascript, any useful tips or resources someone can direct me to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends what you mean by a line. For simple number of newlines, Robusto's answer is fine.

If you want to know how many *rows* of CSV data that represents, things may be a little more difficult, as a CSV field may itself contain a newline:

```
field1,"field
two",field3
```

...is one row, at least in CSV as defined by [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). (It's one of the aggravating features of CSV that there are so many non-standard variants; the RFC itself was very late to the game.)

So if you need to cope with that case you'll have to essentially parse each field.

A field can be raw, or (necessarily if it contains `\n` or `,`) quoted, with `"` represented as double quotes. So a regex for one field would be:

```
"([^"]|"")*"|[^,\n]*
```

and so for a whole row (assuming it is not empty):

```
("([^"]|"")*"|[^,\n]*)(,("([^"]|"")*"|[^,\n]*))*\n
```

and to get the number of those:

```
var rowsn= csv.match(/(?:"(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,\n]*)(?:,(?:"(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,\n]*))*\n/g).length;
```

If you are lucky enough to be dealing with a variant of CSV that complies with RFC4180's recommendation that there are no `"` characters in unquoted fields, you can make this a bit more readable. Split on newlines as before and count the number of `"` characters in each line. If it's an even number, you have a complete line; if it's an odd number you've got a split.

```
var lines= csv.split('\n');
for (var i= lines.length; i-->0;)
    if (lines[i].match(/"/g).length%2===1)
        lines.splice(i-1, 2, lines[i-1]+lines[i]);
var rowsn= lines.length;
```

Comment: I've had to add a `*` at the end to get the last line. The final regex that worked for me was: `("([^"]|"")*"|[^,\n]*)(,("([^"]|"")*"|[^,\n]*))*\n*`

Answer (score 5):

To count the number of lines in a document (once you have it as a string in Javascript), simply do:

```
var lines = csvString.split("\n").length;
```

Comment: Ah cool. Didnt really think of that solution, Ill try it out. Thanks!

Comment: This does not give the correct results when there is new line in a value of csv.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the '.' to match everything on a line except the newline at the end-
it won't count quoted new lines. Use the 'm' for multiline flag, as well as 'g' for global.

```
function getLines(s){
    return s.match(/^(.*)$/mg);
}

alert(getLines(string).length)
```

If you don't mind skipping empty lines it is simpler-
but sometimes you need to keep them for spaceing.

function getLines(s){
    return s.match(/(.+)/g);
}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code in Typescript.

FileReader is needed to obtain the contents.

Returning a promise makes it easy to wait for the results of the asynchronous readAsText and onload function.

```html
const countRowsInCSV = async (csvFile: File): Promise<number> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        const cvsData = event.target.result;
        const rowData = cvsData.split('\n');
        resolve(rowData.length);
      };

      reader.readAsText(csvFile);
    } catch (error: any) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};


const onChangeFile = (selectedFile: File) => {
  const totalRows = await countRowsInCSV(selectedFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to count number of rows in a csv then you can use this example..

http://purbayubudi.wordpress.com/2008/11/09/csv-parser-using-javascript/

It takes the csv file and in a popup window display number of rows..